# Interacting with the UniSwap contract fails depending on the time

Tags: uniswap, bot

My goal is to copy Uniswap Token Swaps. In order to achieve that I listen to newly finished blocks, get the tx's within that block, and pick the right ones out.

Now that I have found a tx that I would like to copy, I extract the liquidity pool out of the tx and initiate my own token swap using Uniswap's V2 Router. Here I am using the `swapExactETHForTokens` fn.

The weird thing is that once I try to swap when the source tx just has been executed, my tx fails.

But on the other hand if I feed my script the source tx hash some time later (like 10min) my script can do the swap successfully.

My questions/thoughts:

1. One thing that I can think of is the slippage. So that the minAmountOut is outdated and thus fails. However I have set the slippage to 75% for testing purposes and it still fails. My input amount is $2.
2. Could it be that there are some kind of fees (from the token swap) I have to calculate? See the addresses in the footer. Should I continue to use `swapExactTokensForETH` or should I use `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`?
3. When looking up the tx's within a block using `provider.eth.getBlock(blockNr, true)`, do I maybe get tx's that haven't been executed yet? My thought is that I am fetching an unconfirmed tx and therefor am unable to fetch the correct data out of a transaction, as if the source tx would change.

Note: I am **not** trying to build an MEV bot. I am copying a trade and want it to execute the block after. I am only interested in tx's that just have been executed not ones that are pending in the mempool.

```
sourceTx: 0xd6f36c309466b491e7f65de03c9fc3cab4be6b2b27bee76c551a9c33a66a3c7a
destTx (failed): 0x6e469605bc6b325850cdd1906d57896c6f4d51648eef4af20d317dcc6d09c9cf
destTx (succeeded): 0x7b8c1feccf025dd9a861c610ce72d1e62690f42ca0732abc6d22ab88ffa7d85b
token: 0x6982508145454Ce325dDbE47a25d4ec3d2311933
```